# Selenium 2 get all cookies on domain

Tags: groovy, webdriver, geb

All. I have problem with getting cookies on domain.
i try get cookies:

```
def "go to site"() {
    when:
        go "http://bla-bla-bla.bla"
    then:
        title == "Bla-bla-bla"
        // check cookies
        String cookies = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("name1").getValue()
        println cookies
}
```

but cookies with `name1` geting on other domain, not `http://bla-bla-bla.bla`, `name1` it's cookies on domain `http://ululu.ulu` and a try get all cookies, on all domains(sites),  but I did not get.

Please help me get all cookies on all domains(sites). Thank you.
My English sucks.

Comment: Do you mean 1) you're seeing cookies from all domains and you ONLY want cookies from the bla-bla-bla domain OR 2) You are only seeing cookies from the bla-bla-bla domain and you want cookies from all domains?

Comment: 2 option, you can help me?

Comment: check out answer to a similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22238612/296280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium only gives you access to the cookies for the currently active domain. That is, cookies that are relevant to the current browser state.

There's no way around this that I know of.

Comment: thanks! But if i use groovy for getting cookies? I can get data not currently domain?

Comment: What about the www sub domain? Is that relevant to the current browser state?

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need to use plugins to get all cookies (*including httpOnly and secure cookies*).
If you use ChromeDriver, you can get all cookies from the browsers profile folder.

**They are stored in an sqlite database file in ./profile/Default/Cookies**

Example for java/selenium:

```
//set Browsers profile folder with ChromeOptions:

String intendedProfileDestinationPath = "C:/temp/somefolder";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+intendedProfileDestinationPath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

//...visit one or more pages...    

//use sqlite to access file:

try {
  // db parameters
  String url = "jdbc:sqlite:"+pathToSqliteCookiesFile;
  // create a connection to the database
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
String sql = "SELECT * FROM cookies";
ResultSet result = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
//... iterate resultset ...
```

Get sqlite drivers via maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.28.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you only want cookies from the pages you visited, make sure to delete the complete folder contents if you restart your selenium browser.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Implemented the same thing with C# and your Java-examples guided me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help @Markus! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this using a Mozilla firefox [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/get-all-cookies-in-xml) which will save all cookies in XML format under current profile directory. This add-on will save cookies from all domains and can be accessed using webdriver.

For more details on implementation, refer to following blog:
http://automationoverflow.blogspot.in/2013/07/getting-cookies-from-all-domains.html

Please remember to vote if this answer is helpful to you.